# reattach fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an activity that all it does is it displays a fragment. under some certain circumstances when navigating back and from the activity, the activity gets recreated. The problem is that in this case, the fragment inside the activity is there (it is displayed after the activity is recreated) but not attached to the activity.

how can I reattach the fragment to the activity ?

Comment: when activity gets recreated you have to add the fragment

Comment: you mean I maintain a static reference from outside the activity and replace it with the current fragment ?

Comment: when your activity is recreated, the fragment gets destroyed. So you have to create new instance of fragment and add it again.

Comment: @AkshayBhat I know this, but my fragment is a very big one with many informations and states that I want to keep, I need to get the handle to this fragment and reattach it

Comment: Ok, but you cant retain the fragment view. If you want to retain the data which is in fragment, then use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: @AkshayBhat could you please show me how ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)`. Basically, this will let you use the same instance of the fragment regardless of Activity's condition.

Here is what says the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) and here goes an excellent [tutorial](http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/) to get you started.

Comment: this was helpful, I think I will use findFragmentByTag and re-add the fragment to the activity.